# Wordpress TwentyTwenty Theme Search Results page

Tags: wordpress

I am using TwentyTwenty theme. In the search results page it shows only the search results texts. I want to show the permalinks of those pages below the search result texts. Which file is to be edited.

Thanks in advance

```
<?php

$archive_title    = '';
$archive_subtitle = '';

if ( is_search() ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $archive_title = sprintf(
        '%1$s %2$s',
        '<span class="color-accent">' . __( 'Search:', 'twentytwenty' ) . '</span>',
        '&ldquo;' . get_search_query() . '&rdquo;'
    );

    if ( $wp_query->found_posts ) {
        $archive_subtitle = sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: Number of search results */
            _n(
                'We found %s result for your search.',
                'We found %s results for your search.',
                $wp_query->found_posts,
                'twentytwenty'
            ),
            number_format_i18n( $wp_query->found_posts )



        );
    } else {
        $archive_subtitle = __( 'We could not find any results for your search. You can give it another try through the search form below.', 'twentytwenty' );
    }
} elseif ( ! is_home() ) {
    $archive_title    = get_the_archive_title();
    $archive_subtitle = get_the_archive_description();

}

if ( $archive_title || $archive_subtitle ) {
    ?>
```

Comment: Posts are coming from template-parts/content.php file in twenty twenty theme.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You must create a child theme of TwentyTwenty and create your own `search.php` template file. If you make changes to the TwentyTwenty theme directly, once there is an update, you will lose all of your changes. This is a larger issue than just editing a file. Please read: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Answer (score 0):

I created search.php with following simple code :

```
<?php 
/**
 * Template Name: Search Page
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<main id="site-content" role="main">

<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="container" style="font-size: 17px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="search-post-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
        <div class="search-post-link" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_permalink(); ?></a></div>
        <hr>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>



<?php get_footer();
```